# Applications of Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Let $f\in C^1$. Prove that for every $x_*$ : $(\nabla \times f)(x_*)=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi \epsilon ^2} \int_{\partial B_\epsilon (x_*)}f(x)dx$

I know that 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi \epsilon ^2} \int_{\partial B_\epsilon (x_*)}f(x)dx =\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi \epsilon ^2} \int_{B_\epsilon (x_*)}\nabla \times f(x)dx
$$

But how can I continue from here? As I obviously can't calculate explicitly the right side of the equation...

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like $\int_{B_\epsilon (x_*)} \nabla \times f \cdot \mathbf{n} dS$ in the integral on RHS?

Comment: @rafa11111 Why? And also if so, how to continue?

Comment: I suppose you used [Kelvin-Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem) to get the second expression. However, it states that the integral of $f$ along a closed path $C$ is equal to the integral of $\nabla \times f$ in the surface enclosed by $C$. Therefore, the integral on RHS must be evaluated in a surface. I think that you can get the original equation from the second one by using the fact that the area of $B_\epsilon(x_*)$ is proportional to $\epsilon^2$, which is also dividing the RHS. It's just a guess.

Comment: For the 3D case I have recently posted this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994383/how-do-i-use-stokes-theorem-to-find-curl/2994472#2994472) to the question "*[How do I use Stokes' theorem to find curl?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994383/how-do-i-use-stokes-theorem-to-find-curl).